# URL Regex - Unknown URL

Tags: regex, url

I've built a Zend Framework CMS, where navigation links are built up from parent/child associations, e.g.

http://youdomain.com/About/history-of-company/early-years (each element is a child page of the previous)
or
http://yourdomain.com/About

These are sample URLs, as this is a CMS I don't know how the client will name the pages, but using the above examples I need a single piece of regex that would return 'About' if there are no slashes or 'early-years' if there are slashes.

The reason for the single regex is because it'll go into a catch all route in application.ini

Thanks in advance,
Marc

Answer (score 0):

```
/(\w+)$
```

Returns the part of the URL after the last slash. You can use modrewrite it something like:

```
/(\w+)$ render.php?page=$1
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to pull out the contents if there isn't a slash? Basically, the url is comprised of page names which are then set as a param to call from the database, so my catch all would need to return everything if there isn't a slash, or just the last part (as you've indicated) if there is a slash... Cheers